# A tour around the world - what am I in America?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, language

> In the Netherlands, I am a symbol of religion
> But in Germany I would decay
> In France, if I move you, I am dishonest
> And in Sweden, I like to fish all day

But what am I in America?

Comment: You're Swedish fish

Comment: @Moose not quite

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are

> Red

In the Netherlands, I am a symbol of religion

> rood -> [rood cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rood)

But in Germany I would decay

> rot

In France, if I move you, I am dishonest

> rouge -> rogue (move "u")

In Sweden I like to fish all day

> röd

Comment: Still convinced the last one is Swedish fish

Comment: This is correct